# How to convert IMediaSample to a bitmap

Tags: c#, bitmap, directshow, directshow.net

Using the `ISampleGrabberCB` interface how would I use the `SampleCB` IMediaSample to a bitmap?

For example:

```
int ISampleGrabberCB.SampleCB( double SampleTime, IMediaSample pSample )
    {
        Bitmap frameBitmap = new Bitmap(pSample);
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct conversion of media sample into bitmap. Media sample is a piece of data coming through streaming pipeline, and can be video frame, uncompressed and compressed, audio packet, block of file bytes etc. Obviously, there is no meaningful conversion from non-video media samples.

If your Sample Grabber is set to accept RGB data (or it's RGB by a coincidence), you *possibly* can create a `Bitmap` object right on top of this data if you provide correct stride (pitch) and pixel format. Otherwise, you will have to perform additional format conversion.